# Creating a value of a type union with discriminator field

Tags: typescript, types

My problem is best illustrated with an example:

```js
interface A { tpe: 'a' }
interface B { tpe: 'b' }
type AB = A | B

const abMaker = (ab: AB): AB => {
  return { tpe: ab.tpe }
}
```

The return statement here has the following error:

```
  Type '{ tpe: "a" | "b"; }' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Types of property 'tpe' are incompatible.
      Type '"a" | "b"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.
        Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.
```

The compiler is not able to infer that the value returned is a valid `AB` because the value of type `"a" | "b"` is not valid for *either* `A` or `B` individually.

I'm able to get this to work by "type-checking" the value of `tpe`:

```js
const abMaker = (ab: AB): AB => {
  switch (ab.tpe) {
    case 'a': return { tpe: ab.tpe }
    case 'b': return { tpe: ab.tpe }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How about just `return ab`?  

Comment: The better way to do this is [upgrade to TS3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#smarter-union-type-checking) and use your original code... does that answer suffice or do you need something for a specific version of TypeScript?

Comment: @jcalz hah! I promise the real-world problem I'm having isn't this contrived. thanks for that link, it seems like they've addressed this issue in TS3.5 -- I'm currently on 3.4. It's unfortunate that I'll have to upgrade to get this working, but at the same time, it's good to know the language is constantly improving!